# OOP prototype.method call this.method

Tags: javascript

```
var fn = function() {


    this.method1 = function() {

        return this.public;
    };


    this.method2 = function() {

        return {

            init: function() { return this.public; }
        }
    };


    fn.prototype.public = "method prototype";
};
```

create object fn

```
var object = new fn();

object.method1() // "method prototype"

object.method2().init(); // undefined
```

this.public Prototype in  method2().init() function run return undefined ?

Is there an alternative to Prototype?
thank you.

Comment: why -1 ? just asked you a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the different scope in which `this` is bound on `init` function of `method2()`, so try this:

```
this.method2 = function() {
    var self = this;      
    return {
        init: function() { return self.public; }
    }
};
```

so

```
object.method2().init(); // return "method prototype"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot wrong with this.

But the direct answer to your specific question is that calling `init` returns undefined because its reference to `this` is to the inner object that you've created and not the instance that you think it refers to.

I suggest you stop trying to solve this particular problem and learn the basics of prototypal inheritance in JavaScript

Comment: Also, I know it's only example code, but `public` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript even though it's not actually used. Avoid using reserved words as identifiers

Answer (score 0):

This `this` in the `init` function is the object returned by `object.method2()`, which has no `public` property on it.